# C# and .NET: is Buffer.BlockCopy thread-safe for structs?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Basically the question is in the title. If I have an array of structs, will Buffer.BlockCopy behave properly in multithreaded environment? In other words, what will happen if during execution of Buffer.BlockCopy some thread tries to update a field on one of the stored structs? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/teyhh36d.aspx documentation says static methods of Buffer (BlockCopy is static) are guaranteed to be thread-safe for simple types. But if my struct contains only simple types, can this guarantee stretch a little bit into my favor?

Comment: I imagine you need to create your own lock if it's not specified as a thread safe operation on the documentation. I can be wrong, but I imagine that's the case.

Comment: The question is wrong. [`Buffer.BlckCopy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx) cannot be used on struct arrays. It  will throw `ArgumentException` if *src or dst is not an array of primitives*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Buffer.BlockCopy` is not an atomic operation on it's own.  There's nothing stopping any other threads from either modifying fields of items in the array the array itself while the `BlockCopy` is being performed.

Comment: According to docs, it's thread safe when dealing with simple types. So your statement is not quite correct.

Comment: Really, you think that `BlockCopy` magically stops everything else from accessing instances in an array *and* changing elements in the array?  How would it be able to do that?  "Thread safe" for static methods just means they won't change any shared state within the containing class.  i.e. shared state in `Array`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/teyhh36d.aspx states that static methods of Buffer are thread-safe when used with int, long, etc., i.e. simple types.

Comment: As I explained, they're thread-safe to themselves (e.g. `Array` in this case).  They can't possibly know about every other piece of data on the computer in order to make everything else thread-safe.  Using a thread-safe method does not make *your code* thread safe.

Comment: Sorry, I am not following. They say "Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe." What does it mean? Can you give me an example.

Comment: A member is "thread safe" only if it doesn't modify *it's own* data.  If it doesn't modify it's own data, it's not doing anything that any other thread could jump in the middle of and corrupt data.  e.g. `BlockCopy` doesn't do anything to shared state within the `Array` class, so it's "thread safe".

Comment: Ah, I see -- it has no shared state so there is nothing that should break it if a method is called from a different thread while the first one is running.

Comment: Right, nothing within the `Array` class.  What you pass to `BlockClopy` is outside the `Array class.